# Horizontal checklistbox

Tags: .net, winforms, checklistbox

I have multiple check box lists on my winform, but the downward flow of the list doesnt look too appealing.'

I was wondering if there is a way to force a checklistbox to display its items horizontally, instead of vertically.

I have tried MiltiColumn and ColumnWidth, but the items are still vertically listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way would be a `FlowLayoutPanel` in which you can add checkboxes. They will then be sorted from left to right.